# How to use an application database without touching its schema

Tags: database, database-design, architecture

If you have another application that uses data of an existing database and needs some more, and you don't want to change the schema of the existing database, how do you do that?

Background of my question: We use an IBM product (Connections) to store user profiles. But we have lots of custom requirements (lots of custom fields and logics), so currently we create a few more tables, views and functions in the backend database of Connections to store the custom data. However, as it is IBM's internal database and we are not supposed to touch it, when we upgrade Connections, all our custom tables, views and functions are gone.

So we decide to move out our custom things. But the problem is we still need to join with the data from Connections. (Or not database join, just some other way to integrate with the data before presenting to the users. )

If we create a federated table in our own database, we can create tables and views like we used to. But would it have performance issues? And we are still going to be heavily depend on IBM's schema and have to assume they don't change it. Is it a good approach?

What are the other options we could consider?

Answer (score 0):

> If we create a federated table in our own database, we can create tables and views like we used to. But would it have performance issues?

Probably.  Your application code would have to do joins between the IBM database tables and your database tables.

I'm assuming that Connections uses DB2.  If you bring up your own DB2 database, I think you can do SQL joins between two separate DB2 databases.

Either way, this code should reside in a separate data access package made up of data access objects.  The rest of your applications would use the data access package.

> And we are still going to be heavily depend on IBM's schema and have to assume they don't change it.

IBM will change their schema, and you have to plan on making corresponding changes to your database and / or application.

> What are the other options we could consider?

You could copy the IBM data from their database to your database.  You still have to make changes to the copy process when the IBM schema table definitions change.